# link to delete a file from a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails 2.3.8 app i am trying to write a link in a view that passes the filename to the method in a controller that deletes a file from a directory. Haven't been able to get the syntax right. I've updated the code below to reflect Tobias' suggestions. It works, except for file names that have spaces in them.

In the documents_conroller.rb file is the following method:

```
def file_cleanup
  File.delete("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/downloads/#{params[:filename].gsub /[^\.\w]/, ''}") 
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @files.each do |f| %>
   <% str = f.gsub(/^.*\//, '') %>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <%=str%>
      </td>
      <td>
          <%= link_to "Del", file_cleanup_path(:filename => str) %>
      </td>
   </tr>
<% end -%>
```

In the routes file:

```
map.file_cleanup '/file_cleanup', :controller => 'documents', :action => 'file_cleanup'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want `params`, with an "s", not `param`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up resource routes with named routes.

**With a named route**

Route:

```
map.file_cleanup '/file_cleanup', :controller => 'documents', :action => 'file_cleanup'
```

In the view, pass through the filename as a parameter to the link url:

```
link_to "Del", file_cleanup_path(:filename => str)
```

Then in the controller, use `params[:filename]` to get the value:

```
File.delete("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/downloads/#{params[:filename].gsub /[^\.\w]/, ''}")
```

**With a resource route**

In the route, add a new member method:

```
map.resources :documents, :member => { :file_cleanup => :get }
```

In the view, you use the link you have now:

```
link_to "Del", file_cleanup_document_path(str)
```

In the controller, use `params[:id]` to get the value:

```
File.delete("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/downloads/#{params[:id]}")
```

**Warning:**

As Dan points out, using a user modifiable value directly in `File.delete` is a really bad idea. Here's a link to the Rails guide on sanitizing filenames:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#file-uploads

Comment: You _are_ going to recommend that he sanitise params[:filename] first, yes?

Comment: This view is not available to the general public. Only Three staff members have access to this page to use it to manage documents available to clients through a different view. You still see a problem?

Comment: @Jay: It's not a problem per se (my use case is very similar to yours), but as always, things can go wrong and/or people who shouldn't have access to your view could get access to it. Better safe than sorry I suppose. Thanks again for your question. It helped me out :)